# Python progress bar while loading

Tags: python

I am using a facial recognition program and after executing it, it takes a few seconds until it prints. During those seconds of python loading, is it possible to display a percentage loading bar?

While python is executing and loading, there will be a display of 1% followed by 2%, but on the same line and the 2 replaces the 1 percent.

If you're unclear, simple comment I will help communicate.

The facial recognition code:

```
import face_recognition
picture_of_me = face_recognition.load_image_file("me.jpg")
my_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(picture_of_me)[0]
unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")
unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)[0]
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([my_face_encoding], unknown_face_encoding)
if results[0] == True:
    print("FRS successful: Match found")
else:
    print("FRS unsuccessful")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the face_recognition module so It will take me time to write a complete answer, but did you consider using [TQDM](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)?

Edit:

If you wish to update the progress bar after each line, you should do something like:

```
with tqdm(total=100) as pbar:
    picture_of_me = face_recognition.load_image_file("me.jpg")
    pbar.update(20)
    my_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(picture_of_me)[0]
    pbar.update(20)
    unknown_picture = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")
    pbar.update(20)
    unknown_face_encoding =face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)[0]
    pbar.update(20)
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces([my_face_encoding], unknown_face_encoding)
    pbar.update(20)
```

Comment: I did, I was able to make a loading bar but I am not sure how to link it with those lines of code. I dont believe you have to be familiar with the code that I have you just need to know how to implement that into a loading bar while its processing @TJR

Comment: What event will change the percentage of the loading bar? Do you have an access to an iterator or do you want the percentage to change after each line?

Comment: basically, from when you press enter, until it prints, there is about a 5 second wait while it processes. In that time, I want there to be some sort of loading bar. It can be of any sort @TJR